# how do you add functionality to a button without using javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have added a button to my HTML code and i want to add some functionality to it so that when i press it, it performs a task but the problem is i do not know any javascript so how can i do it without using javascript.

i tried creating a function with a function name that i assigned to the button during assigning the onclick option. i created the function inside the head tag in the html code.

Comment: You could use a <form> to trigger a server action. On server, you may have more options available.

Comment: Please add your code in a sample to let us understand better what you're trying to do.

Comment: also onclick is a handler for manipulation using JS

Comment: If you really are not prepared to use JS you can't sensibly use a button element. You could look into anchor elements (a) or input elements with type checkbox - they enable you to do a little bit without JS, but TBH you need to learn a bit of JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Lucky, welcome! Please show some [reprex] of what you created so we can help you with your specific problem. Don't make us guess what you did...

Comment: "_i want to add some functionality_" **What functionality?** You might find [ask] helpful in writing a good question.

Answer (score 0):

depends on the what type of task you want it to perform, you can simply go to different links by using anchor tags, or navigate to different parts by having ids using id. Also you can use CSS to trigger different styles on the state of your buttons. your question is very vague it doesn't looks like you are facing any issue.